# mvn exec:java problem executing default demo application?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to compile and execute the default Maven application.  I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly, but from what I can tell the application correct compiles, yet won't execute via maven.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

1. Create project

`$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=demoapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false`

2. Adjust compiler settings in POM (I'm using JDK 21)

   <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>          <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
3. Compile

`mvn compile`

success

4. Test that worked

```
$ cd target/classes 
$ java com.mycompany.app.App     
Hello World!
```

5. Now the problem I observe, use `mvn exec:java`

```
$ mvn exec:java
[INFO] ---------------------< com.mycompany.app:demoapp >----------------------
[INFO] Building demoapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ demoapp ---
[INFO] ---------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project demoapp: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

6. `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>demoapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>demoapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

7. `mvn -DmainClass=com.mycompany.app.App exec:java` results

```
~/src/java/demoapp]$ mvn -DmainClass=com.mycompany.app.App exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.mycompany.app:demoapp >----------------------
[INFO] Building demoapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ demoapp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.847 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-15T18:53:53-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project demoapp: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

8. directory structure

```
$ tree .
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── com
│   │           └── mycompany
│   │               └── app
│   │                   └── App.java
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── mycompany
│                   └── app
│                       └── AppTest.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── com
    │       └── mycompany
    │           └── app
    │               └── App.class
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    └── maven-status
        └── maven-compiler-plugin
            └── compile
                ├── default-cli
                │   ├── createdFiles.lst
                │   └── inputFiles.lst
                └── default-compile
                    ├── createdFiles.lst
                    └── inputFiles.ls
```

t

Comment: You need to post pom.xml with your question
`mvn -DmainClass=com.mycompany.app.App exec:java` does what?

Comment: @g00se I posted this to the OP

Comment: @notaorb can you try argument "-Dexec.mainClass=com.mycompany.app.App" rather then "-DmainClass" ?

Comment: Sorry - that's what I should have said. Yes, that should work, but you can also configure the plugin as I've show below to save you the bother of doing that

Answer (score 0):

Your exec plugin is not configured. Try instead the following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>demoapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>demoapp</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: So I was following Maven in 5 minutes from Apache to create the dir struct at https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html.  I had to manually edit pom.xml for Java > 7.  Now I have to manually edit for exec of the application.  Is this typically steps required?  Figured it would work out of box after dir struct was created.  Thanks

Comment: I think you're probably justified in thinking that. I don't quite know why the non-interactive archetype doesn't make a runnable exec:java out of the box

Comment: What do people typically do?  Create their own pom.xml or modify the archetype's creation?  Or perhaps just run the jar in the target directory manually?  Looking for the compile, run sequence with mvn

Comment: I just start with the framework and modify as needed. More specifically I have a script that takes the archetype and passes parameters to it from input